# Is it possible to use typesafe activator offline?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator, typesafe

I have tried running activator from the distribution, but even when I set the proxy configuration, it seems that there are some hosts I cannot access from behind my corporate firewall. This includes Amazon S3, which seems to be being used when I try to run the ui.

Is it possible to use activator solely from the distribution I have downloaded (which appears to contain a local ivy repository)? Currently, it does not seem that play, sbt, activator etc. are well-suited to a corporate environment. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use the activator terminal command. For this you'd need no internet connection. Actually I never use the activator UI unless I want to try out some examples. Run `activator help` from within your play application's root folder to see the list of possible commands. E.g. with `activator run` you'd run your application.

Comment: Thanks - I've tried this. However, it still seems to be trying to download dependencies when I run either command from within my app's root folder. Ultimately, it fails with the error: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.4.2: not found

Comment: Yes, initially you need to be connected to the internet. Ah, now I understand the problem. You're behind a proxy. You sure tried the proxy setting https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Installing?

Comment: Yes, the issue is that my firewall blocks access for some of the repos. Given there is a local repository in the activator distribution though, is it possible to resolve everything from here rather than checking online for snapshot changes?

Comment: Sorry, doesn't know too.